# Default button on master page also working for content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, default

I have a form on master page

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="ibnQuickSubmit" defaultfocus="txtQuickSearch">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuickSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnQuickSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="ibnQuickSubmit_Click"
                                ImageUrl="~/Images_v4/Common/Go.png" />
  </form>
```

I have set the above button `ibnQuickSubmit` as default button on enter key press when `defaultfocus="txtQuickSearch"`
It works fine but when i click on any other text box on any content page and press enter, in dat condition also the default key press of master page works.
Can any one throw some pointer about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using Panel

```
<asp:Panel id="form1" runat="server" DefaultButton="ibnQuickSubmit">

 // Some controls and code //

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuickSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibnQuickSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="ibnQuickSubmit_Click"
                            ImageUrl="~/Images_v4/Common/Go.png" />

 // Some controls and code //

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: It works fine in IE and Chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox